# Find particular sibling node using JOLT

Tags: jolt

Input JSON:

```
[
  {
    "NM108": "XX",
    "NM109": "123123123",
    "NM102": "2",
    "id": "NM1",
    "NM103": "ABCD WXYZ",
    "NM101": "85"
  },
  {
    "N301": "1234 MAIN ST",
    "id": "N3"
  },
  {
    "N401": "QWEQWRWEE",
    "id": "N4",
    "N402": "AB",
    "N403": "12341234123"
  },
  {
    "NM108": "AM",
    "NM109": "345345345",
    "NM104": "Kqwer",
    "NM102": "1",
    "id": "NM1",
    "NM103": "Touok",
    "NM101": "LI"
  },
  {
    "N301": "1369 Riddley Ripper Blvd",
    "id": "N3"
  }
]
```

Problem:
This is a part of a big edi 837 standard input. Using JOLT script, we need to find only the N301 node (i.e. node with value "1234 MAIN ST") that comes right after NM101=85.

With my limited knowledge of JOLT, I can't seem to find a way to only find that N301 node where value is "1234 MAIN ST". All i can get is an array of "1234 MAIN ST" and "1369 Riddley Ripper Blvd". I can't seem to find a way to restrict the look up to only one that is a sibling of a particular node.

Any possible solution?

Comment: Is that N301 key always in second element of an array? Or maybe you need only first occurence of these key?

Comment: Magda, thanks for responding back.  Each NM1 segment represents a party and N3/N4 segments that follow represents their address. With the example mentioned above, "1234 MAIN ST" is the street address of "ABCD WXYZ", "1369 Riddley Ripper Blvd" is the street address of "Touok". In other words, N3s will follow every NM segment. Not guaranteed to be the second element of the array.  

Ideally, one would expect N3/N4 segments to be a sub object of NM1 rather than being at the same level. But here this  is the input from 3rd party this way. We don't have control over how they generate it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find an answer for your problem. I'll watch those question because I am cuorius of the solution:)